# Change json call on ng-click

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, angularjs, model-view-controller

I am new to angular, and I want to know how I can change the json array on ng-click. I tried different methods, but the code didn't work. I am not sure how to create this functionality.

Here is my code. I want the the default to be chapter 1 when the app loads, and when the user clicks the menu link, it changes to whatever chapter number is passed into the function.

**menu.html ---- view**

```
<li>
    <a href>Practice</a>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="words in allTerms track by $index">
            <a href class="{{$index}}" id="{{ $index }}" ng-click="testing($event); PracticeTerm(); changeData('chapter2');" >{{ words.term }}</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

**I am using a service to load the data**

```
app.factory('quest', ['$http', function($http) { 
return $http({
 method: 'GET',
  url: 'data/study.json'
    }).success(function(data) { 
        return data;
      }) 
      .error(function(err) { 
          return err; 
     });
    }]);
```

**Here is the code snippet from my controller that I have so far.**

```
    quest.success(function(data) {
    $scope.data = data;
    $scope.total = data.chapter1.length;
    $scope.allTerms = data.chapter1;
// stores current term index    
    $scope.shared = [];

 $scope.changeData = function(thechapter){       
 return $scope.total = 'data.'+ thechapter + '.length';
 $scope.allTerms = 'data.' + thechapter;
 console.log($scope.total);
 };

});
```

**JSON data ---- sample data**

```
"chapter1": [
    {
        "id": "1",
        "chapter": "1",
        "term": "Closingstage",
        "pronun": "kloh-zing steyj",
        "soundfile": "",
        "definition": "Closing stage definitions ---------CLOSING STAGE DEFINITION"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "chapter": "1",
        "term": "CaptialWords",
        "pronun": "CAP-I-Tal Worlds",
        "soundfile": "",
        "definition": "Capital Worlds definitions----------------CAPITAL WORLD DEFINITION"
    }
],
"chapter2": [
    {
        "id": "1",
        "chapter": "2",
        "term": "Closingstage2222",
        "pronun": "kloh-zing steyj222222222",
        "soundfile": "",
        "definition": "Closing stage definitions ---------CLOSING STAGE DEFINITION22222222"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "chapter": "2",
        "term": "CaptialWords22222222222",
        "pronun": "CAP-I-Tal Worlds",
        "soundfile": "",
        "definition": "Capital Worlds definitions----------------CAPITAL WORLD DEFINITION222222222222"
    }
]
```

Comment: What do you mean "it changes"?  What changes?

Comment: I mean the data from the chapter changes. For example, if the user clicks chapter 2, the data from the chapter 2 array will show when called.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following function instead of the one in your controller

```
$scope.changeData = function(thechapter){       
 $scope.allTerms = data[thechapter];
 console.log($scope.total);
 return $scope.total = data[thechapter].length;
 };
```

note that I've moved the return line to be the last line in the function so the other lines run .